# Error when trying to compare instance of a class with a variable type

Tags: java, eclipse, if-statement, nullpointerexception, null

I am having a problem with a Java Nullpointer exception. So basically I am making a code that will ask the user to input X data, and then according to the data type he typed, it will add them as the according variable type, while comparing it to other previous existing variables.

```
    varvar A;
    varvar B;
    varvar C;
    System.out.println("Choose what to do:");
    System.out.println("1. Set variable A");
    System.out.println("2. Set variable B");
    System.out.println("3. Set variable C");
    b = src.nextInt(); //next int into variable b

if(b==1){

    while (src.hasNext()) { //Next thing the user is going to input

          if (src.hasNextInt()) { // If it's an integer, do this :

              if("Integer".equalsIgnoreCase(B.getClass().getSimpleName())){B = null;};
              if("Integer".equalsIgnoreCase(C.getClass().getSimpleName())){C = null;};
```

These last 2 lines are basically what I'm struggling with. B and C are class varvar instances. I am trying to delete B and C IF their existing content is an Integer variable. But whenever I add these two lines I get a Nullpointer exception. Here is the earlier varvar class code :

```
              public static class varvar {
    int x;
    boolean y;
    double z;

    public varvar (int x){
        this.x = x;
    }

    public varvar (boolean y){
        this.y = y;
    }

    public varvar (double z){
        this.z = z;
    }
```

Can anyone help me please? I am trying to find a way to compare B and C variable types with Integer, and delete them if they indeed contain variables of Integer type.

Comment: It seems `B.getClass()` is `null`. put debug point and check.

Comment: @bmthaker B is already null when initialized, but the if statement is only supposed to run if B is an Integer, so then it can null its value.

Comment: I don't understand what are you trying to achieve? what is `varvar`?  Put condition like `if(B!=null && "Integer".equalsIgnoreCase(B.getClass().getSimpleName()))` to handle null pointer.  it will not execute condition if `B` is null and not throw any *error*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Java is a case sensitive language.  B and b are not the same thing.  In your example B is never set, so it is null.
2. Java has reflection, so all the gymnastics with Strings are muddying up the code.  Instead, try this:

   if (Integer.isInstance(B)) {B = null;}

When you look at this, and you know in advance (as the writer of the code) that B is an instance of varvar, you can see that the code is nonsensical because an object of type varvar can never be of type Integer.

I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish here, so I can't give you much more input than this.

Comment: the varvar class is something I made, to be able to make 3 different instances, that can contain booleans, integer, and double type variables. Whatever I decide to input in the varvar instance, it will add it as the corresponding type, is there any way that I could test the type of the variable contained in the instance please?

Comment: Is each instance of varvar supposed to hold one result, or three results?

Comment: Just one. Is it holding three results? Is that why my code won't work?

Comment: You don't need the varvar class.  Make each of your variables (a, b, and c) to be of type Object.  Your input routine will have to make the decision whether to instantiate the variable as an Integer, Boolean, or Double (note capitalization - Double is a class, but double is a primitive), based on the content of the String or whatever criterion you have.

Comment: It will.  If you say *Object a = Integer.valueof("34");  logger.debug(a.getClass().getName());* , you will see java.lang.Integer in your log.

Comment: I know I found out, and as a last question, if a is null, can I find a way to avoid `nullExceptionError` when trying to `a.getClass().getName()` ?

Comment: If we keep this up we'll get moved to chat.  if (a != null) { stuff = a.getClass.getName(); } else {stuff = "(null)";}

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize **varvar** A, B and C to contain an instance of your class.

In any case, if you want to have the class object associated with a type, use

```
varvar.class.getSimpleName()
```

The class associated with your variables A,B and C is **varvar** or a subclass thereof.

Also, it is unclear what you mean by 'delete' them. You seem to set a variable to null.

Hint for better legibility: class names should start with an uppercase character and variables with a lowercase character.